# gcloud compute scp - permission denied error

Tags: file, permissions, google-compute-engine, scp

I would like to transfer file from my local machine to Google cloud instance. Here is my command:

```
gcloud compute scp "C:\Temp\esim_replication.ipynb" nlp-3:
```

Here is error message:

```
pscp: unable to open ./esim_replication.ipynb: permission denied
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-clou
d-sdk\bin\sdk\pscp.exe] exited with return code [1].
```

This is brand new error. Everything worked fine 2 weeks ago. I am on Windows 7 locally and ran cmd as Administrator. I tried the above command with and without quotations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run --verbosity debug and provide the output?

Comment: @PatrickW Thank you so much, by trial and error method I figured out that there is already identically named file at destination. So problem solved, but I am glad to learn about `--verbosity` option

Comment: Awesome, can you post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I already had identically named file at destination. This caused the error. But Patrick W comment is very helpful

Answer (score 4):

Go to gcloud via ssh:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "your_zone" "instance_name" --project "project_name"
```

Give full access to your file:

```
sudo chmod 777 esim_replication.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds this like I did: I had a similar error message, and what did the trick for me was using sudo: `sudo gcloud compute scp [LOCAL] [REMOTE]`. Apparently there was the need for updating the project ssh metadata (even though copying in the other direction worked just fine).

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same error while transferring from my local Windows desktop to Debian VM in GCP.

Changed the permission of the destination folder to 777.

```
gcloud compute scp source_folder/File1.txt VM_instance_name:destination_folder
```

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

What? from a windows machine?

'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.